# Move from Libgdx Activity to Android Activity

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have my layout(Main menu) implementations of game in android and the main running game in Libgdx. We can move from android to Libgdx by this code

```
 AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
            cfg.useGL20 = false;
            initialize(new GameActivity(), cfg);
```

but how to move from libgdx game to android mainmenu activity

Comment: can u please specify what type of activity u want to switch to

Comment: @KumarSaurabh I want to switch to android activity 
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android MainActivity class (the one where you took that code from):

```
intent = new Intent(this, MainMenuActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you need to call it from inside the core project classes. You need to use an interface.

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

Comment: thanks a lot @Lestat and this code also helped me [link]https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup

Comment: @lestat I tried the above solution, and then when I try to come back to libgdx screen I get a blank screen. Any idea y?

Comment: That sounds like OpenGL Context Loss. It means you didn't reload your textures(images). Usually libgdx does it for you if you use "new Texture(args)" to create a texture. That seems to not be the case with your code.